# Getting SelectListItems of MultiSelectList from SelectList

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

I have created a SelectList and initialised it as follows:

```
SelectList _selectList = new SelectList(new List<SelectListItem>
{
    new SelectListItem{Text = "aa", Value="bb"},
    new SelectListItem{Text = "cc", Value = "dd"},
    new SelectListItem{Text = "gg", Value = "ff"}
});
```

(It's a sample. Normally, I add 15 or 20 SelectListItems)

Then I try to get the text and value of this `_selectList` instance in order to set a instance:

```
foreach (var item in _selectList)
{
    var a = item.Text;
    var b = item.Value;
}
```

At this point, `item.Text` returns `System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem` and `item.Value` returns `null`.

If I check `_selectList` with cursor during dubugging, all `SelectListItems` and its values under `base{System.Web.Mvc.MultiSelectList}` and I cant get these values.  Question is "how can I?".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use SelectList you can use it like this:

```
var model = new IndexModel()
{
    lista = new SelectList(new string[] { "BMW","Volvo" }),
    listb = new SelectListItem[]
        {
            new SelectListItem {Text = "aa", Value = "bb"},
            new SelectListItem {Text = "cc", Value = "dd"},
            new SelectListItem {Text = "gg", Value = "ff"}
        },
     listc = new SelectList(new SelectListItem[]
              {
                       new SelectListItem {Text = "aa", Value = "bb"},
                       new SelectListItem {Text = "cc", Value = "dd"},
                       new SelectListItem {Text = "gg", Value = "ff"}
              }, "Value", "Text")

};
```

It's just helper to build List of items. You can definitely use IEnumerable directly in helpers:

```
@Html.DropDownList("dropdown", Model.lista)
@Html.DropDownList("dropdown2", Model.listb)
@Html.DropDownList("dropdown3", Model.listc)
```

EDIT: updated code. Actually after looking into SelectList source you'll see it derives from MultiSelectList -> http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/4284ca5270b9#src/System.Web.Mvc/MultiSelectList.cs and is using DataBinder to eval text and value based on given fields. So you can get it working with list of SelectListItems if you explicitly give field names (just like for listc).

mz

Comment: it's good idea for creating and using SelectList and SelectListItem but I am interested in my question,too. Why i can't get texts and values of my instance:)

Comment: Because SelectList takes values directly from Enumerable. In case when you pass it List<SelectListItem> it'll read whole SelectListItem object as item, not reading Text and Value from those objects. Not sure if I explained that clear ;-)

Comment: Confusing for me. I can use my sample to show with dropdownlist on Htlm.DropDownList("","viaViewData") but i can't get values. If It read whole SelectListItem object as item,I think it shouldn't show all text on dropdownlist but it can. Am I wrong?

Comment: I've updated answer, please take a look maybe will clear out more :-)